# Running batch script containing a multiple job array on multiple nodes

Tags: slurm

I'm looking to run batch script file on multiple nodes. The script file includes an array of multiple jobs. I want slurm to run each jobs on 3 nodes. I tried to give this code but the slurm is issuing this warning:

```
 Warning: can't run 1 processes on 3 nodes, setting nnodes to 1
```

The script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=Littest
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=28
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --out=output.txt
#SBATCH --exclude=node2,node11,node43,node44
#Jobfile=Li

declare -a arrK=(Li2.in Li6.in Li8.in)

module load intel
module load qe/6.5

for File in ${arrK[@]};
do
echo $File
mpirun -np 84 pw.x -i $File  > out.$File &
echo "1 Job Complete.Nice."
done

echo "all job complete"
wait
```

How can i fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do that would be

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=84
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=28
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
```

and you won't need to specify `-np 84` to `mpirun`. It will take it from the Slurm allocation.

The error message you get comes from the fact that Slurm must have at least 1 task per node. So if you request 1 task and 3 nodes, it gets confused.

Comment: I see , a new user here! Thank you for the help!